# C++: Cosine is wrong, should be zero. 3Pi/2

Tags: c++, double, trigonometry

I have a program and I'm trying to calculate`cos(M_PI*3/2)` and instead of getting 0, as I should, I get -1.83691e-016

What am I missing here? I am in radians as I need to be.

Comment: Your value of `M_PI*3/2` isn't close enough to 3π/2 to get 0.

Comment: What value has been set for M_PI?

Comment: Even if `M_PI*3/2` evaluates to the closest representable value to the real number 3π/2, that's probably far enough away that `cos` *shouldn't* return 0.

Comment: Due to machine precision, when dealing with decimal numbers on a computer you can't assume perfect accuracy.  Therefore cos(M_PI*3/2) != 0.0. But what you have is close to being zero. So you can always test for close to zero.

Comment: Any suggestions on the best way of going about fixing that?

Comment: mandatory link to: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: @user2059300 one possibility is not to calculate the result of intermediate values, but to keep the symbols. That is really complicated in C(++), but quite easy in prolog, for example. Anyways, never use `==` for floating point values but always test if you are close to some epsilon.

Comment: @user2059300 Depending what you're trying to do at larger scale, Boost's [interval arithmetic](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/numeric/interval/doc/interval.htm) library may help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, M_PI is not a very portable macro and is usually good to about 15 decimal places, depending on the compiler you use - my guess is you're using Microsoft's C++ compiler.

Second, if you want a more accurate (and portable) version, use the Boost Math library:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/tutorial/non_templ.html

Third, as Kay has pointed out, pi in itself is an irrational number and therefore no amount of bits (or digits in base 10) would be enough to accurately represent it. Therefore, What you're actually calculating is not cos(3*pi/2) exactly, but "the cosine of 3/2 times the closest approximation of pi given the bits required", which will NOT be 3 *pi/2 and therefore won't be zero.

Finally, if you want custom precision for your mathematical constants, read this: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/tutorial/user_def.html

Answer (score 5):

The number `M_PI` is only an approximation of π. The cosine that you get back is also an approximation, and it's a pretty good one -  it has fifteen correct digits after the decimal point.

Comment: In the math.h I have it has 22 significant digits.  Likely nowhere near enough accuracy to expect 0.0 on this calculation.

Comment: @CPlusPlusOOAandD a double can only represent ~16 decimal digits, so 22 digits are plenty.

Comment: @Kay that is heavily dependent on which compiler is used.  For example, today's 64-bit world supports more digits than a 32-bit compiler.  The IEEE-754 standard addresses floating point.  A Wikipedia summary is here: [IEEE floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754).  The complete standard is available at the IEEE site, but probably not free unless an IEEE member or currently enrolled in an engineering degree program.

Answer (score 4):

Given the discrete nature of `double` values, the standard margin of error against which to test for numerical equality is `numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  double x = cos(M_PI*3/2);
  cout << "x = << " << x << endl;
  cout << "numeric_limits<double>::epsilon() = "
       << numeric_limits<double>::epsilon() << endl;
  cout << "Is x sufficiently close to 0? "
       << (abs(x) < numeric_limits<double>::epsilon() ? "yes" : "no") << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
x = << -1.83697e-16
numeric_limits<double>::epsilon() = 2.22045e-16
Is x sufficiently close to 0? yes
```

As you can see, the absolute value of `-1.83697e-16` is within the margin of error given by epsilon `2.22045e-16`.

Comment: I only wanna note that `numeric_limits::epsilon` is afaik defined to be the difference between 1.0 and the next representable value by the type. That works for small numbers like OP's but for big numbers you'll probably need a different epsilon.

Answer (score 2):

Pi is irrational, the computer cannot represent the number perfectly. The small error to the "correct" value of pi causes the error in the output. Being 1.83691 × 10<sup>-16</sup> off is still pretty good.

If you want to learn more about the restrictions of actual system and the impact of little errors in the input, then refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_stability.

Comment: Also, review this high level summary of [Numerical Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_Analysis).  An epsilon of 10<sup>-16</sup> is very small and very close to zero.  In other words, it will be necessary to establish an acceptable accuracy and then check against it.